# php how i can change my label in loop

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

I have an array in loop while like this when I var_dump it.

```
array (size=73)
    0 => string '1' (length=1)
    'address' => string '1' (length=1)
    1 => string '2' (length=2)
    'street_no' => string '2' (length=1)
array (size=73)
    0 => string 'vbfgh' (length=5)
    'address' => string 'vbfgh' (length=5)
    1 => string 'fgfd' (length=4)
    'street_no' => string 'fgfd' (length=4)
array (size=73)
    0 => string 'vbfgh' (length=5)
    'address' => string 'vbfgh' (length=5)
    1 => string 'fgfd' (length=4)
    'street_no' => string 'fgfd' (length=4)
array (size=73)
    0 => string 'vbfgh' (length=5)
    'address' => string 'vbfgh' (length=5)
    1 => string 'fgfd' (length=4)
    'street_no' => string 'fgfd' (length=4)
```

I want disply data on screen for first data is

```
`AddressMain: 1
 streetMain: 1

 .....
 AddressLeft: vbfgh
 street1Left: fgfd

 .....
 AddressRight: vbfgh
 streetRight: fgfd

.....
AddressCenter: vbfgh
streetCenter: fgfd

.....`
```

How I can change my label like this if this code in loop while ? 
And this is my code

```
 while( $row = pg_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "AddressMain:".$row['address'];
      echo "streetMain:".$row['street_no'];
      echo "<br/>";
      echo ".......";
 }
```

Plz help me how I can change my label in this loop ?
thanks

Comment: Can you define *'label'* in this context?

Comment: i want change the label of data

Comment: What is the *label of data*? The array name? The array keys? The string that appears before each array value?

Comment: The first item of array is Main, the second is left,..right, and final is Center? are you right?

Comment: @George label text string before values array

Comment: @Time I realised when reading the [answer given](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26377620/1612146).

Comment: @Quang  is just my simple for example

Answer (score 2):

Use an array to define labels, then loop around it.

```
$labels = array('Main','Left','Right','Center');
$i = 0;

while( $row = pg_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Address".$labels[$i].":".$row['address'];
    echo "street".$labels[$i].":".$row['street'];
    echo "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: It was kinda hard to interpret what OP meant... But I guess I'm right :)

Comment: Oh I see now, I wasn't paying enough attention to that desired output. +1.